# Spotify API - Can I find the Completion % of a song?

Tags: spotify

I am working with some clients who want to be able to see the average completion percentage their tracks are listened to on Spotify (e.g. 50% is half the song).

The API documentation doesnt show how this can be done, but i have seen some label platforms offering this data (AWAL etc)

Am I missing anything obvious?

API Document Link: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/

Thanks in advance!

I've looked through the documentation and no obvious field  for completion time

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if you think it is correct

Answer (score 2):

As for many APIs there seems to be a separate one for Analytics https://analytics.spotify.com/faq/api#api

It also looks like you need to be a label/author registered with Spotify https://analytics.spotify.com/c/api/